# verified middleware is not working in laravel? not getting the verification page in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, verify

```
<pre>
```

I am providing some files. Please help me. I am frustrated with laravel, but I have to complete this project.
When I register a new user, it sends me or redirects me to the dashboard instead of the email verification page.
But emails are sending properly, but email/verify is not working. please help me how to solve this problem

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\EmailVerificationRequest;
use App\Http\Controllers\HomeController;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
});

Route::get('/tandc', function () {
    return view('t&c');
});

Route::get('registration', function () {
    return view('reg');
});

Route::get('login', function () {
    return view('log');
});

Route::get('well', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);

Route::get('/home',[HomeController::class,'index'])->name('home');

Route::get('/email/verify',function(){
    return view('auth.verify');
})->middleware(['auth'])->name('verification.notice');
```

**RegisterController**

I am using laravel/ui for authentication

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }
   
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'username' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'password' => ['string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
            'brandname' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'fname' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'lname' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 
            'unique:users'],
            'phone' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'address' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        ]);
    }
    
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'brandname' => $data['brandname'],
            'fname' => $data['fname'],
            'lname' => $data['lname'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'phone' => $data['phone'],
            'address' => $data['address'],
        ]);
    }
}
```

**User Model**

not understanding why they are not working

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'username',
        'password',
        'brandname',
        'fname',
        'lname',
        'email',
        'phone',
        'address',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];
   
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

**HomeController**

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(['auth', 'verified']);
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }
}
```

i am to frustrated because of it

Comment: "email/verify not working" ? what do you mean? the page doesn't show up, there is an error?

Comment: Laravel docs has a [whole section](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/verification) about email verification, I see you're missing some things they do to set it up correctly, like `The Email Verification Handler` and protecting routes with the `verified` middleware